# How do I use mod_rewrite to provide RESTful URLs, hiding my script name?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm new to using `mod_rewrite`.  Could some one tell me how to change this url

```
http://example.com/blog/index.html?page=1
```

to

```
http://example.com/blog/page/1
```

Thanks a bunch!
Kohei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase   /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

try the above lines in your .htaccess